# Sheet name is a number, How do I call it in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheets named `1` `2` `3` and so on.
The numbers are listed on a sheet in column H.

```
For i = 5 To LastRow
    If Range("J" & i).Value = "NOT OK" Then
       Sheets(Range("H" & i).Value).Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next i
```

This tries to call sheet(1) as in 1 as the first sheet. But `1` is actually (currently) sheet(3).

I tried to use `"` to make Excel read it as a string but it fails too.

```
Sheets(Chr(34) & Range("H" & i).Value & Chr(34)).Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
Worksheets(CStr(1))
```

CStr will convert to string so you reference by name not as Index.

Or use the `.Text` property

```
Sheets(Range("H" & i).Text)
```

Comment: **Please** loose the `Select`, you're better than this ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado True. But I see the point QHarr is making. The code works with `Sheets(CStr(Range("H" & i).Value)).Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

Comment: @Andreas it will work without the `Select`, I know the point QHarr was trying to make, but still it's recommended to stay away from using `Select` 99.9%

Answer (score 3):

Some more notes on your code:

Firstly, to solve your problem, you can append empty string to implicitly convert number into string (`&` forces an implicit conversion):

```
For i = 5 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 10).Value = "NOT OK" Then
       Sheets(Cells(i, 8).Value & "").Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next i
```

Secondly, when dealing wiht multiple worksheets, then you better specify sheet whenever you reference any range, like:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet 'although, it would be better to use Sheets("sheet name")
```

Then your code would become:

```
For i = 5 To LastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = "NOT OK" Then
       Sheets(ws.Cells(i, 8).Value & "").Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next i
```

Or, as suggested in coment:

```
With ws
    For i = 5 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, 10).Value = "NOT OK" Then
           Sheets(.Cells(i, 8).Value & "").Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: or, you could use `With ws`